# Redirection Subfolder Htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

I want a redirect using htaccess I have a post name wordpressurl/curious and also a folder named curious
What I want is if a user tries to access

1. wordpressurl/curious
2. wordpressurl/curious/
3. wordpressurl/curious/subfolder

   note trailing slash in 1 and 2 and 3 is subdirectory. All of them should give 404 error wordpress page using htaccess only

**Edited**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Wordpress_Work/realestate/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /Wordpress_Work/realestate/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: I edited my question and added my current htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the wordpress post that is the same as a **curious** directory by making the changes indicated below. Change **curious** to whatever your actual directory/post is.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Wordpress_Work/realestate/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

#add an OR
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
#OR if the URI is curious or curious/ or curious/subfolder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/Wordpress_Work/realestate/curious(/.*)?$ 

RewriteRule . /Wordpress_Work/realestate/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: accessing /curious gets redirected to /curious/
and /curious/ is treated as folder but for subfolder this works fine. Can you help?

Comment: When I request `/curious` there is no redirect though the browser does insert the trailing slash to give `/curious/` as you describe. Also both `/curious` and `/curious/` give the the same result. Do you have any other rules in your .htaccess file, and can you give me the full url that you are using to test that works for `subfolder` but not `curious/?`.

Comment: I have a subfolder xyz and sub-sub folder xyza
here is link http://creativescripters.com/samples/staging/xyz/
http://creativescripters.com/samples/staging/xyz/xyza/
there are posts with same name xyz and xyza
my htaccess
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /samples/staging/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#add an OR
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
#OR if the URI is xyz or xyz/ or xyz/subfolder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/samples/staging/xyz(/.+)?$ 


RewriteRule . /samples/staging/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: I replaced the `+` with a `*` so the content after curious is optional.  Try making the same change to your file i.e. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/samples/staging/xyz(/.*)?$ ` and it should work

Comment: That is odd: when I try `http://creativescripters.com/samples/staging/xyz/` or `http://creativescripters.com/samples/staging/xyz` on your site I get a WordPress page, presumably because it gets rewritten to `index.php`.  Do you get the same result, and is this what you wanted? If not, let me know the result or what does not work as you expect.

Comment: Thanks it worked, +1 and correct answer for you. can we add 2 folders like curious and curiosity?

Comment: Yes it worked for me , can we add 2 folders like curious and curiosity?

Comment: try `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/Wordpress_Work/realestate/(curious|curiosity)(/.*)?$`

Answer (score 1):

If you are putting `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` you can't have same name for the page and physical directory . that's the point of using it.

Try skipping the `rewritecond` , though I've never tried it before . for me , I'd change the page name or add a suffix.

Comment: Is it possible that we donot access the folder but the wordpress page . for eg i have folder named test as well as post test
I want if user tries to access /test/ it should display wordpress post instead of directory

Comment: not that I know of , sorry . the way I understand htaccess is for making exceptions for urls other than physical folders/files order , like calling controls or making 2 urls end up on the same page.in your case , 1 url has 2 possible targets .