# Limit web folder access to specific URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, web, blogs

I am hosting two different websites using one hosting package.

My initial website is self-built and runs from the public_html directory of my host let's call this 'http://www.website1.co.uk'

I also have a Word Press blog running in a folder under the public_html - so '/folder_2', let's call this 'http://www.website2.co.uk' - this URL currently points to '/folder_2' and will load the blog when entered in to a browser.

At the moment the blog is also accessible by entering 'http://www.website1.co.uk/folder_2/'.

I would like to be able to limit access to 'folder_2' to just 'website2.co.uk' - preventing somebody typing in the 'website1.co.uk/folder_2' path and being able to view the blog.

What's the best way to achieve this, bearing in mind the folder in question is running a Word Press blog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this in your .htaccess file in folder_2

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{http_host} !website2.co.uk
RewriteRule .* http://website2.co.uk
```

that would redirect anyone who goes to website1.co.uk/folder_2 to website2.co.uk, but if you just want them hit a 404 put this in .htaccess instead

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{http_host} !website2.co.uk
RewriteRule .* - [R=404,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

1# move folder_2 out of public_html(you really should do that).

2# rewrite all request of 'http://www.website1.co.uk/folder_2/' to 404 in htaccess

Check below link:

[Redirection Subfolder Htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273798/redirection-subfolder-htaccess)